# What prerequisites does the rpm-maven-plugin require?

Tags: java, maven, rpm-maven-plugin

What does the `rpm-maven-plugin` plugin require to build an rpm?

What command line utilities and/or other programs need to be installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [rpm-maven-plugin source code](https://github.com/mojohaus/rpm-maven-plugin/) it calls a number of Linux tools:

- rpm
- rpmbuild
- rpm2cpio
- expect
- mkdir
- sh

Above list is not complete. I don't believe this is documented and tools will depend on plugin goal e.g. `rpm2cpio` is used only by `unpack` goal.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I couldn't find anything other that it requiring java 1.6 and maven 2.2.1 on the website.

Comment: Also the source code link returned a 404 error for me... Should it be just https://github.com/mojohaus/rpm-maven-plugin/ ?